# Showing Months in Words in Oracle Fusion

Tags: oracle, oracle-fusion-middleware

I'm Trying to Display Months in Words in `Oracle Fusion` as a List of Values but it doesn't work.

**code**

```
SELECT distinct to_char(start_date,'Month')
from per_all_people_f papf
ORDER BY to_char(start_date,'Month')
```

**results**

```
01
02
03
... etc
```

I Also Tried `to_char(start_date,'Mon')` to show Jan, Feb .. etc, but nothing works, only numbers are returned, what's the issue here?

Comment: I don't know Oracle Fusion. What is START_DATE column's datatype? What is its contents?

Comment: date, for example : ```2022-08-22T00:00:00.000+00:00```

Comment: This is raised as an issue on MOS [ticket here](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Fusion%20Applications/1664251_1.html). You can sign in with your Oracle account to see the full details.